# How to add line breaks in jumbled html code

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

I have html code that looks all mashed up like:

```
<html><head> <script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = runJcript('fixads()');</script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://wik253.googlecode.com/files/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://wik253.googlecode.com/files/main5.css" type="text/css"> </head><body></body>
```

It is very hard to read and work with, Is there a way to bring it to proper format like:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = runJcript('fixads()');
</script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://wik253.googlecode.com/files/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://wik253.googlecode.com/files/main5.css" type="text/css"> </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So its more readable and workable.
Is their a tool or an online script that can help me do that?

Thanks,
Praney

Comment: get an IDE that does that for you, like Aptana Studio's `CTRL+SHIFT+F`

Comment: A quick Google for HTML formatter is all it takes ...

Comment: @SirCrispalot Thank you I found : http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html
I was just struggling to find the exact keyword for the search on google.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help guys but don't think there was anything in the question so it could be marked sown.
I thought this site was about asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a text editor which is written for coding it is common that the editor has a function for cleaning up the indentation. In Kate you find the function under Tools > Clean Indentation.

If you are generating HTML you could take a look at HTML Tidy: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you I found an online script to do it easily:

http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

So if anyone is looking for the same they can check it out too.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your use case. If you just need to do it for a few documents here and there, you can use a beautifier like: http://jsbeautifier.org/ (beautifies HTML code too)

If you need it in your application, you can check out the `js-beautify` engine that powers the site above: https://github.com/einars/js-beautify

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Tidy, there's an online version over [here](http://infohound.net/tidy/).
Or you can download it to use in your application [here](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

Many IDE's have clean-up options like Dreamweaver.